# How can I resolve Namespace conflict in WordPress Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed a WordPress Plugin in PHP PSR-4 Autoloading.
When I duplicate the plugin with a different name and active from the plugin section it replaces remove plugin side nave by the Last plugin.
Suppose : 
First Plugin Name: MainPlugin
Second Plugin Name: TestPlugin

..First Plugin and second plugin's side menu is not the same as position, slug, name but first plugin sidenav remove when I active second Plugin. 
My plugin Link: https://github.com/emrancu/PluginMaster
Please help me: How to resolve this issue? And how to activate two plugins without any problem?

Comment: With all respect. Please post the relevant code here rather than expecting us to analyze your full code on GitHub repo. Thanks!

Comment: Namespace in both Project is the same : App\

Answer (score 0):

It's Not possible to create dynamic Namespace. You can not run same namespace with two projects.
If you are active then WordPress calls the last namespace because the first namespace replace by the last namespace if the namespace is the same.